# zf2 router: One module makes the router unable to find another module. How can I make both work?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-framework-routing

We're just starting out with zf2, so someone else made a Thumbnail server module, and then I added a Lookup server module. I call these servers because they're both RESTful apis. Initially they seemed to work together, but someone made some changes to my module, and now the Thumbnail server won't work unless Lookup is removed from the `application.config.php` list of modules. The Lookup server works regardless. Looking over the code, I don't see how the changes made to Lookup would affect Thumbnail. The error I'm getting looks like this:

```html
<h1>A 404 error occurred</h1>
<h2>Page not found.</h2>
<p>The requested controller was unable to dispatch the request.</p>
<dl>
<dt>Controller:</dt>
<dd>Lookup\Controller\Lookup</dd>
</dl>
```

Here's what `application.config.php` looks like:

```php
<?php
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        'SanRestful',
        'Album',
        'AlbumRest',   
        'Thumbnail',         
        'Lookup',
        'AP_XmlStrategy',
    ),
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        'config_glob_paths'    => array(
            'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
            'config/autoload/{,*.}' . (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ?: 'production') . '.php',
        ),
        'module_paths' => array(
            './module',
            './vendor',
        ),
    ),
);
```

As you can see, there's the initial Album module, and a few other experimental ones. My Lookup module uses the excellent [AP_XmlStrategy module by Allessandro Pietrobelli](http://www.alessandropietrobelli.com/tag/xml/).

Below is the Thumbnail `module.config.php`. It has a constraint that's probably not being used because there are no arguments called "id", but that shouldn't mess things up, should it?

```php
<?php
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Thumbnail\Controller\Thumbnail' => 'Thumbnail\Controller\ThumbnailController',
        ),
    ),

    // The following section is new and should be added to your file
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'thumbnail' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/thumbnail[/:action][/:output]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Thumbnail\Controller\Thumbnail',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),

    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'thumbnail' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

And the Lookup `module.config.php`, with identifiers obfuscated:

```php
<?php
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver'         => 'Pdo',
        'dsn'            => 'pgsql:dbname=<dbname>;host=<host>;port=<port>',
        'username'       => '<username>',
        'password'       => '<password>',
        ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'
                    => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
        ),
        'aliases' => array(
            'db' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter',
        ),
    ),
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Lookup\Controller\Lookup' => 'Lookup\Controller\LookupController',
        ),
    ),
    // The following section is new and should be added to your file
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'lookup' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '[/:action][/:version][/:resource][/:code][/:resource_xref]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action'         => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'version'        => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'resource'       => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-|\.]*',
                        'code'           => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'resource_xref'  => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-|\.]*',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Lookup\Controller\Lookup',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'lookup' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
        'strategies' => array(
            'ViewJsonStrategy',
            'ViewXmlStrategy',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Are there any obvious mistakes here that I'm missing?

Comment: The only weird thing I see is the route defined in the Lookup module: 'route'    => '[/:action][/:version][/:resource][/:code][/:resource_xref]' It basically means that all requests will go to the Lookup module.

Comment: Ruben is absolutely correct.  Consider breaking that mega-route up into individual routes per-action.  Or you could try constraining action to only match a set of particular action names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Requests can be matched by multiple routes. An example: the url /foo can be matched by a literal route `/foo` and also the route `[/:action]`. To distinguish the two routes, **the order how you configure them matters**.

What happens, the routes are matched in *LIFO* order, so the **last route must be the most explicit**. In the "/foo" example, this config will match the literal:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'test1' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '[/:action]',
                'defaults' => array(
                    //
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'test2' => array(
            'type'    => 'literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/foo',
                'defaults' => array(
                    //
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

However, in the below config, the literal will **never** be matched, because `[/:action]` is a possible match for `/foo`.

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'test2' => array(
            'type'    => 'literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/foo',
                'defaults' => array(
                    //
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'test1' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '[/:action]',
                'defaults' => array(
                    //
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Now take a look at your two modules. The first (Thumbnail) has a route `/thumbnail[/:action][/:output]`. it starts with a **literal part**. Then your second module (Lookup) has a route `[/:action][/:version][/:resource][/:code][/:resource_xref]`.

Now if you get back to the LIFO order, any route starting with `/thumbnail` will match already at the Lookup route.

**Solution**

There are two options. First is to swap the order of the modules. This is always an important order if you have inter-dependent relations between modules. Load Lookup first and then Thumnnail, so the thumbnail route is put later in the config. Thus, it matches first. Thus, your app works again.

Then there is the second solution (and imho, the better). You have a "one route to rule them all" in the Lookup, which is not a really good practice. You can get into trouble exactly like you are now, having no idea what went wrong. Thus, specify as much as possible in your routes. Make the first part of the Lookup also literal (is `/lookup[/:action][/:version][/:resource][/:code][/:resource_xref]` not an option?). Or remove action as parameter and make those literal:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'view' => array(
            'type'    => 'segemnt',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/view[/:version][/:resource][/:code][/:resource_xref]',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'action' => 'view',
                    //
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'create' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/create[/:version][/:resource][/:code][/:resource_xref]',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'action' => 'create',
                    //
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'update' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/update[/:version][/:resource][/:code][/:resource_xref]',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'action' => 'update',
                    //
                ),
            ),
        ),
        // And so on
    ),
),
```

This way, your lookup module has a fixed starting point and matches only if those first parts are in the request uri. Then your `/thumbnail[/:action][/:output]` is completely decoupled from the Lookup routes.

Comment: That was it, thanks! And thanks for the in depth explanation.It worked before because I had /lookup in there, but another developer took that out when he made his changes. We're both new to zf2, so neither of us quite understood how the router works. Now it has a unique identifier so we get both thumbnails and lookups, and can expand as needed.